# Pass multiple checkbox values onclick to controller to filter query in Laravel with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, checkbox, filter

I am trying to get the number of the students filtered by campus, year and group with checkbox.

I sort of managed to filter the result with Campus. Well actually with this code, uncheck doesn't work. It still sends checked value.

I need to send Campus, Group and year checkbox values to controller. There is no problem with the controller part. It is all working. If I can send the right values from the checkboxes my query works. I just couldn't figure out the jQuery section.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
var campus = [];
var getfilters = function () {
  console.log(campus);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: 'URL...',
    data: {
      "campus": campus, 
      "_token": "CSRF token..."
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e.responseText);
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#gracebish').html(data)
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.each($("input[name='campus']:checked"), function() {            
      campus.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('#myResponse').html(); 
    getfilters();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3">Campus</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
          <input type="checkbox" name="campus" value="1" id="1"> <label for="1"> Campus1</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
          <input type="checkbox" name="campus" value="2" id="2"> <label for="2"> Campus2</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Group</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
          <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="3" id="group3"> <label for="group3"> 3 Year Old</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
          <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="4" id="group4"> <label for="group4"> 4 Year Old</label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Year</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
          <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="{{date('Y')}}" id="year1"> <label for="year1">{{date('Y')}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
          <input type="checkbox" name="year" value="{{date('Y', strtotime(" +1 year "))}}" id="year2"> <label for="year2">{{date('Y', strtotime("+1 year"))}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but I think the reason why it still sends checked values even you unchecked is because you are not resetting the `campus` array back to an empty array. One solution is to declare the `campus` var inside `change` function and pass it as parameter to your `getFilters` function. Try.

```
var getfilters = function (campus, group, year) {
    ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var campus = [];
    var group = [];
    var year = [];
    $.each($("input[name='campus']:checked"), function() {            
      campus.push($(this).val());
    });
    
    //do also the above on group and year

    $('#myResponse').html(); 
    getfilters(campus, group, year);
  });
});
```

Comment: nice to know! happy coding :)